# Flutter Setting Container with Columns inside a GridView which is inside Expanded class

Tags: flutter

There is a widget by the name mywidget , i want mywidget to take as much space as it is required  .. It is a container that have one column with  rows of image , then text then buttons something like when a product on e-commerce app . I want it to increase as much height it requires .

There isn't anything that is restricting it to take height but still i am getting Render flow with extra pixels, so i have to decrease the size of the image to make it work .

Here is the main container where there is a GridView and in this gridview we have all the MyWidget containers.

```
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Column 1 with vertical scroll and image buttons
                 
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Row 1 with horizontal scroll list
                // Grid with lazy loading and unlimited scrolling
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10),
                    itemCount: 100, // Replace with your actual item count
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      // Replace with your grid item widget
                      return Container(
                        child: MyWidget(),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 5,
                              offset: Offset(0, 3),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
```

// Class MyWidget

```
           @override
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return Column(
               children: [
                 // Row 1: Image
                 Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                   children: [
                     Container(
                       width: 50.0,
                       height: 50.0,
                       alignment: Alignment.center,
                       child: Image.asset(
                         "assets/images/logo.png",
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                     ), // Replace with your desired image
                   ],
                 ),

                 // Row 2: Buttons with icon and text
                 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.alarm,
                  size: 10,
                  color:
                      Colors.black, // Replace with your desired icon color
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 3,
                ),
                Text(
                  "15 MIN",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Add your button onPressed logic here
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors
                    .purple.shade50, // Replace with your desired color
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Imported',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8, color: Colors.purple),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
                 ),

                 // Row 3: Text
                 Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
            'Green Peas ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
          ),
        ),
      ],
                 ),

                 //  Row 4: Small text
                 Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
            '1 pc - 25 gm  (125-175 gm) ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
          ),
        ),
      ],
                 ),

                 // Row 5: Two columns with small text and button with dynamic state
                 Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  '\u{20B9}245',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '\u{20B9}342',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Add your button onPressed logic here
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor:
                    Colors.green.shade50, // Replace with your desired color
              ),
              child: Text(
                'ADD',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 8,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade50),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
                 ),
               ],
             );
           }
```

Comment: Please provide some image of desired result for better visualisation.